# How to post on the wall vkontakte via oauth?

Tags: api, oauth, authorization, vk

Error code:15

Error Message: "Access denied: no access to call this method"

scope=offline,wall

Answer (score 3):

I am faced with such problem few days ago and right now I have no solution. VK support team simply ignore my question about it. The only thing I can say is that from the [official documentation](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) there is no exact answer on that.

> You need the following rights to call this method: wall.
>
> This method is only available to Standalone-apps and web clients using the confirmation window.

But when you go to [permissons details page](https://vk.com/dev/permissions) you find that "wall" scope

> access permission is unavailable for sites (it is ignored at attempt of authorization).